# HTML Angular Material: Hide Columns in a dynamically forming table

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-material

I want to hide columns in my table based on an ID value that is sent to the page upon opening it. I've seen there is a method for tables whose columns are formed as needed... https://github.com/angular/components/issues/9940 this post outlines that. However my table is formed as such.

```
 <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" align="center" class="mat-elevation-z8">
  <ng-container [matColumnDef]="column" *ngFor="let column of getDisplayedColumns()">
    <th  mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef > {{column}} </th>
    <td  mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" > {{element[column]}} </td>
  </ng-container>
    <tr  mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns" ></tr>
    <tr  mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns:  getDisplayedColumns();" ></tr>
 </table>
```

**getDisplayedColumns() should return my array with only the elements I want to show**

I'm confused on how I would implement the above method into my code given that my table is formed differently than the OP's.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a lot of ways to do this, but I had a similar need so created a component and passed in all possible columns.  The component does a lot of special formatting like booleans = "yes" | "no" or dates dates | date:'MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss a', but for your case isVisible is what you seem to need.  A few key pieces:

```
export interface IPaginateRowAttributes {
attributeName: string;
listLabel: string;
listFormat: string;
isAttribute: boolean;
lookupIndex: number;
isVisible: boolean;
}


@Input() rowColumns: IPaginateRowAttributes [] = [];
@Input() yourId


<tr *ngFor="let dynamicListRowAttribute of dynamicListRowAttributes">

<ng-container *ngIf="dynamicListRowAttribute.listFormat=='number' && dynamicListRowAttribute.isVisible==true" matColumnDef={{dynamicListRowAttribute.compositeKey}}>
              <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header (click)="sort(dynamicListRowAttribute.attributeName, true, dynamicListRowAttribute.listFormat)"> {{dynamicListRowAttribute.listLabel}} </th>
              <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element['attributes'][dynamicListRowAttribute.attributeName] | currency}} </td>
            </ng-container>

<ng-container> more format options</ng-container>

ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
let returnHeaders: string[] = [];
for (let detail of displayColumns) {
      returnHeaders.push(detail.dictionaryCompositeKey);
    }
}
```

So right there include ngOnChanges, you could check your ID value and set isVisible per column based on whatever criteria you want to use and let the *ngIf filter the rest.  This is one option anyway, there may be better solutions in terms of performance.